# How to compare values of a data frame to values in another data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, comparison

*I posted this question several days ago, but I was told my description is too confusing. After clarifying my problem and adding an example, however, the question did not receive any further attention. Since I still need a solution, I deleted the old question and now post it in a hopefully better formulation.*

The following example illustrates my problem.

I have two objects. First of these is a data frame that describes each individual's (*id*) group (*group*), a year when s(he) took an action (*do.year*) and the values of a variable (*var*) for every year between years 2010 and 2015 (*var.year*).

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
   id = rep(1:3, each = 6),
   group = c(rep("a", 12), rep("b", 6)),
   do.year = rep(sample(2011:2013), each = 6),
   var = runif(18),
   var.year = 2010:2015)
df
   id group do.year        var var.year
1   1     a    2011 0.90820779     2010
2   1     a    2011 0.20168193     2011
3   1     a    2011 0.89838968     2012
4   1     a    2011 0.94467527     2013
5   1     a    2011 0.66079779     2014
6   1     a    2011 0.62911404     2015
7   2     a    2013 0.06178627     2010
8   2     a    2013 0.20597457     2011
9   2     a    2013 0.17655675     2012
10  2     a    2013 0.68702285     2013
11  2     a    2013 0.38410372     2014
12  2     a    2013 0.76984142     2015
13  3     b    2012 0.49769924     2010
14  3     b    2012 0.71761851     2011
15  3     b    2012 0.99190609     2012
16  3     b    2012 0.38003518     2013
17  3     b    2012 0.77744522     2014
18  3     b    2012 0.93470523     2015
```

The second object consists of data frames for groups *a* and *b* and also contains values of a variable (*var*) for every year between years 2010 and 2015 (*var.year*), but these are the average values of group members. It's a list of data frames, but could also be converted into a single data frame if necessary.

```
avg <- list(
   "a" = data.frame(var.year = 2010:2015, var = runif(6)),
   "b" = data.frame(var.year = 2010:2015, var = runif(6)))
avg
$a
  var.year        var
1     2010 0.21214252
2     2011 0.65167377
3     2012 0.12555510
4     2013 0.26722067
5     2014 0.38611409
6     2015 0.01339033

$b
  var.year       var
1     2010 0.3823880
2     2011 0.8696908
3     2012 0.3403490
4     2013 0.4820801
5     2014 0.5995658
6     2015 0.4935413
```

My goal here is to compare each individual's result indicator to that of the respective comparison group's in a specific year (*do.year*). So, for each individual (*id*), I'd like to take the value of variable (*var*) in the year when an action was taken (*do.year*) and from that value subtract the group average value (*var* in *avg*) of the same year (*var.year*). The result for each individual would be stored in a new variable *diff.var*.

I have only a few weeks of experience with R, so my solution would be to just merge datasets for every group (and variable) and then do the calculations (below). However, since my original dataset involves 7 groups and 6 variables, it would result in about 1000 lines of code. I also tried looping, but was unable to properly define the loop variable everywhere.

```
df.a <- merge(df, avg[["a"]], by = "var.year")
df.a$diff.var[df.a$group == "a" & df.a$var.year == df.a$do.year] <- 
    df.a$var.x[df.a$group == "a" & df.a$var.year == df.a$do.year] - 
    df.a$var.y[df.a$group == "a" & df.a$var.year == df.a$do.year]
df.a
   var.year id group do.year      var.x      var.y   diff.var
1      2010  1     a    2011 0.90820779 0.21214252         NA
2      2010  2     a    2013 0.06178627 0.21214252         NA
3      2010  3     b    2012 0.49769924 0.21214252         NA
4      2011  1     a    2011 0.20168193 0.65167377 -0.4499918
5      2011  2     a    2013 0.20597457 0.65167377         NA
6      2011  3     b    2012 0.71761851 0.65167377         NA
7      2012  1     a    2011 0.89838968 0.12555510         NA
8      2012  2     a    2013 0.17655675 0.12555510         NA
9      2012  3     b    2012 0.99190609 0.12555510         NA
10     2013  1     a    2011 0.94467527 0.26722067         NA
11     2013  2     a    2013 0.68702285 0.26722067  0.4198022
12     2013  3     b    2012 0.38003518 0.26722067         NA
13     2014  1     a    2011 0.66079779 0.38611409         NA
14     2014  2     a    2013 0.38410372 0.38611409         NA
15     2014  3     b    2012 0.77744522 0.38611409         NA
16     2015  1     a    2011 0.62911404 0.01339033         NA
17     2015  2     a    2013 0.76984142 0.01339033         NA
18     2015  3     b    2012 0.93470523 0.01339033         NA

df.b <- merge(df, avg[["b"]], by = "var.year")
df.b$diff.var[df.b$group == "b" & df.b$var.year == df.b$do.year] <- 
    df.b$var.x[df.b$group == "b" & df.b$var.year == df.b$do.year] - 
    df.b$var.y[df.b$group == "b" & df.b$var.year == df.b$do.year]
df.b
   var.year id group do.year      var.x     var.y  diff.var
1      2010  1     a    2011 0.90820779 0.3823880        NA
2      2010  2     a    2013 0.06178627 0.3823880        NA
3      2010  3     b    2012 0.49769924 0.3823880        NA
4      2011  1     a    2011 0.20168193 0.8696908        NA
5      2011  2     a    2013 0.20597457 0.8696908        NA
6      2011  3     b    2012 0.71761851 0.8696908        NA
7      2012  1     a    2011 0.89838968 0.3403490        NA
8      2012  2     a    2013 0.17655675 0.3403490        NA
9      2012  3     b    2012 0.99190609 0.3403490 0.6515571
10     2013  1     a    2011 0.94467527 0.4820801        NA
11     2013  2     a    2013 0.68702285 0.4820801        NA
12     2013  3     b    2012 0.38003518 0.4820801        NA
13     2014  1     a    2011 0.66079779 0.5995658        NA
14     2014  2     a    2013 0.38410372 0.5995658        NA
15     2014  3     b    2012 0.77744522 0.5995658        NA
16     2015  1     a    2011 0.62911404 0.4935413        NA
17     2015  2     a    2013 0.76984142 0.4935413        NA
18     2015  3     b    2012 0.93470523 0.4935413        NA
```

How should this problem be solved in R? A base R or data.table solution would be preferred.

Comment: What is your expected output for the two data-frames you consider? Keep your question short & remove unwanted details from the question.

Comment: Do you really want to create few data sets or you want to always join to the original data set?

Comment: The results should be in a single data set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a `data.table` solution here's a possible one. I would suggest first to convert your list to a `data.table` with a `group` column. And the just do a join on `var.year` and `group` while `do.year == var.year` and create `diff.var` on the fly. I'm also assuming that you are not really trying to create an identical data set for each group, rather just the original data set joined with `avg` according to your rules. Something like the following

```
library(data.table)
### Create a group column for each list and convert to a data.table
avg <- rbindlist(Map(cbind, avg, group = names(avg)))

### join by var.year and group while do.year == var.year and create diff.var on the fly
setDT(df)[do.year == var.year, 
          diff.var := var - avg[copy(.SD), var, on = c("var.year", "group")]]
df
#     id group do.year        var var.year   diff.var
#  1:  1     a    2011 0.90820779     2010         NA
#  2:  1     a    2011 0.20168193     2011 -0.4499918
#  3:  1     a    2011 0.89838968     2012         NA
#  4:  1     a    2011 0.94467527     2013         NA
#  5:  1     a    2011 0.66079779     2014         NA
#  6:  1     a    2011 0.62911404     2015         NA
#  7:  2     a    2013 0.06178627     2010         NA
#  8:  2     a    2013 0.20597457     2011         NA
#  9:  2     a    2013 0.17655675     2012         NA
# 10:  2     a    2013 0.68702285     2013  0.4198022
# 11:  2     a    2013 0.38410372     2014         NA
# 12:  2     a    2013 0.76984142     2015         NA
# 13:  3     b    2012 0.49769924     2010         NA
# 14:  3     b    2012 0.71761851     2011         NA
# 15:  3     b    2012 0.99190609     2012  0.6515571
# 16:  3     b    2012 0.38003518     2013         NA
# 17:  3     b    2012 0.77744522     2014         NA
# 18:  3     b    2012 0.93470523     2015         NA
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to calculate more than one variable at a time? E.g. if I had a _var2_.

Comment: It is possible but it also depends on the type of calculation and etc.